# displayed html table with button in each row using php code, but not able to access individual row through that button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I displayed a html table within a php while loop extracting some data from a database and included an edit button in the rows of the table to edit the entries in that row (database finally). But , irrespective of on which edit button I click on , it is editing the first row elements only. How can I fix it?

```
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <?php
          $test=1;
          if(!empty($_SESSION['uid']))
          {
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "Hostel";
            $test++;
            $flag=FALSE;
            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection

            if ($conn->connect_error)
            {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }


            // $id=$_POST['complid'];
            $c_name=$_SESSION['name'];
            $c_usn=$_SESSION['uid'];
        ?>
        <div class="container col-md-12" >
          <h1 style="text-color:white;">The posts are listed below :</h1>
          <hr style="box-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;"> 
          <style>
            h1 
            {
              color: white;
            }
          </style>
        <div class="table-responsive" style="border-radius:10px;border:2px solid gray;box-shadow:10px 10px 10px black;background-color:#d2d2d2;">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Post.No.</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Operations</th>
              </tr>

                <?php
                  $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                  {
                ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row{'id'};?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row{'date'};?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row{'title'};?></td>
                <td>
                  <b><button type="button" id="editbut" style="color:yellow;background-color:black;border:1px solid gray;border-radius:3px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Edit</button> </b>
                  <b><button type="button" style="color:white;background-color:red;border:1px solid gray;border-radius:3px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModa2">Delete</button> </b>
                  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit your post here</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Title :</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></textarea>
                              <label for="message-text2" class="control-label">Matter :</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"><?php echo $row['matter']; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Post</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      posttitle = "<?php echo $row{'title'}; ?>";
                      postid = "<?php echo $row{'id'}; ?>";
                      document.getElementById("deletebut").onclick = function () {
                          alert(postid);
                          //location.href = "deletepost.php?id="+postid;
                      };

                  </script>

                  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModa2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirm your delete request:</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                              <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Are you sure, you want to delete this post?</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                          <button type="button" id="deletebut" class="btn btn-danger">Delete post</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
                <?php
                  }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      echo "<script type='text/javascript'alert(\"Please Login.\");>window.location.href = 'sign.php';</script>";
                      exit();
                    }
                ?>          
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- the code silly.

Comment: *Facepalm* @Dagon silly moi. Pop, I coulda had a V8.

Comment: @ OP: Guess my shoesize, win a prize. @Dagon I'll give you first dibs. Hint: It's not a cupie doll.

Comment: my shoes list 3 some times 4 sizes, US, EU, UK; then some times JP - its very confusing @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Dagon CA has a different system and it's called "clues". Some of which asking questions, are walking barefoot right now.

Comment: i thought shoes in CA came in wolf, moose and bear. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Dagon only when they're ["in season"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-k5J4RxQdE) and on sale.

Answer (score 1):

- Your edit button is not contained in a form.
- The form labelled "edit your post" does not contain the database ID of the post.
- Your JavaScript handler for the delete button references an element ID which does not exist.
- You have multiple form elements with the same ID and no name

I could go on, but this is pretty badly broken.